# Dynamically evaluating templated Strings in Kotlin

Tags: templates, dynamic, kotlin

Suppose that I have the following piece of Kotlin code:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val a = "test"
    println(args.first())
}
```

If I pass in an argument `$a`, the output is going to be `$a`. As I understand it Kotlin takes care of String templates by generating the code for the output on compilation, presumably using a StringBuilder. Is there some way to evaluate Strings that aren't in the source code with regards to templates in their current context? String templates are very useful and it'd be great to be capable of evaluating expressions that come from a dynamic context, such as configuration files, but as far as I can tell this can't be done.

Lacking that, what would be a good approach towards this? Invoking a scripting engine?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you need to evaluate arbitrary expressions in this way, then yes, you need a scripting engine. Kotlin has a [JSR 223](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=223) implementation that you can use, see the examples [here (the `kotlin-jsr223-*` projects)](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/tree/master/libraries/examples/).

Here is a basic usage example:

```
val engine = ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByExtension("kts")!!
engine.eval("val x = 3")
val res = engine.eval("x + 2")
Assert.assertEquals(5, res)
```

<sup>The code is taken from [`KotlinJsr223ScriptEngineIT.kt`](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/examples/kotlin-jsr223-local-example/src/test/kotlin/org/jetbrains/kotlin/script/jsr223/KotlinJsr223ScriptEngineIT.kt#L68), and remember to [configure the service via `META-INF`](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/tree/master/libraries/examples/kotlin-jsr223-local-example/src/main/resources/META-INF/services)</sup>

Comment: A scripting engine for Kotlin itself sounds perfect. I wanted to avoid bringing JavaScript or JRuby into it when the the arguments operated on would be Kotlin ones.

Comment: By the way, I've just tried it for myself and found [a problem](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-17921) with the 1.1.2 release of this tool, so if you encounter it too, then I'd recommend using 1.1.1 until it's fixed.

Comment: 1.1.2 here, but after some experimenting I found that to access variables not declared in the script itself but passed in via bindings to the scripting engine, you have to us a construct `bindings["var_name"] as Type`. Is that intentional and will it stay that way? In Rhino you can just do something like `var_name + 2` and it evaluates. In the end the requirements I need this for are probably gonna necessitate writing a parser anyway, but it was interesting to try.

Comment: @G_H, I think you can work that around by binding a value first and then evaluating a code line that will declare it as a local variable in the script. Something like this: [(gist)](https://gist.github.com/h0tk3y/1966663456235e674c6971f5c1911db4)

Answer (score 14):

For completeness, here are also some ways to dynamically evaluate String templates in your Kotlin code.

The normal behavior of String templates is to evaluate the contents of the String at compile time. It will not change during the execution of your code:

```
fun main() {
    var subject = "world"
    val hello = "hello $subject"

    subject = "stackoverflow"
    println(hello)
}

// Output: hello world
```

There are multiple workarounds for this restriction:

### Lambda function

You can wrap your String in a lambda function, so everytime you call your function, it will evaluate a new instance of the String.

```
fun main() {
    var subject = "world"
    val hello = {"hello $subject"}

    subject = "stackoverflow"
    println(hello())
}

// Output: hello stackoverflow
```

**Advantage**

- Support String operations

**Disadvantage**

- Must call it like a function

### Anonymous object

You can create anonymous objects (similar to static in Java) and override the toString method.

```
fun main() {
    var subject = "world"
    val hello = object { override fun toString() = "hello $subject"}

    subject = "stackoverflow"
    println(hello())
}
    
// Output: hello stackoverflow
```

**Note:** I would not recommend this approach.

**Advantage**

- No function call needed

**Disadvantage**

- Does not support all String operations

### Property Delegation

You can delegate property operator functions to an external class to achieve the dynamic evaluation of String templates.

```
import kotlin.reflect.KProperty

fun main() {
    var subject = "world"
    val hello: String by dynamicStringTemplate { "hello $subject" }

    subject = "stackoverflow"
    println(hello)
}

// Output: hello stackoverflow
 
class dynamicStringTemplate(var value: () -> String) {
    operator fun getValue(thisRef: Nothing?, prop: KProperty<*>): String {       
        return this.value()
    }
 
    operator fun setValue(thisRef:  Nothing?, prop: KProperty<*>, value: String) {
        this.value = {value}
    }
}
```

**Advantages**

- Supports all String operations
- Works the same as a String

**Disadvantage**

- Additional class must be created

Answer (score 2):

> Is there some way to evaluate Strings that aren't in the source code with regards to templates in their current context?

There are no template strings in your code sample and `a` is unused. Am I understanding correctly that you'd like to do something like `val evaluated = evalStringTemplate(template, arg1, arg2, ...)` with `template` being a `String` like `"$a"` and arg1, arg2, ... being arguments for the template?

If so, there's no Kotlin-specific way to do this, but you can use the Java [Formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) class.

Comment: Formatting Strings does just that, it formats. Kotlin templates can contain expressions, such as arithmetic operations, boolean logic, method calls etc. That's more what I'm after.