# Can an integer in Kotlin be equal to an math expression?

Tags: kotlin

I am making a program that solves a math expression, for example, 2+2. Can I set an integer equal to something like this:

```
val input = "2+2"
input.toInt()
```

Comment: No - `input` is just a string and `input.toInt()` will fail.  (You could try this yourself).

Comment: You may want to put "recursive descent parser" into your favorite search engine...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Kotlin doesn't have any built in ways for evaluating arbitrary expressions. The [`toInt`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/to-int.html) function can only parse a `String` containing a single whole number (it's just a wrapper for [`Integer.parseInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String))).

If you need this functionality, you'll have to parse and evaluate the expression yourself. This problem is no different than having to do it in Java, for which you can find discussion and multiple solutions (including hacks, code samples, and libraries) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/evaluating-a-math-expression-given-in-string-form).

Comment: The same scripting approach is available with Kotlin as a scripting language, see this section https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew11.html#javaxscript-support and the linked sample.

Answer (score 2):

No you cannot convert directly a String Mathematical Expression to Integer.

But you can try following approach to convert String Mathematical Expression to Integer ->>

```
    var exp: String = "2+3-1*6/4"
    var num: String = ""
    var symbol: Char = '+'
    var result: Int = 0

    for(i in exp)
    {
        if(i in '0'..'9')
            num += i
        else
        {
            if(symbol == '+')
                result += Integer.parseInt(num)
            else if(symbol == '-')
                result -= Integer.parseInt(num)
            else if(symbol == '*')
                result *= Integer.parseInt(num)
            else if(symbol == '/')
                result /= Integer.parseInt(num)

            num=""
            symbol = i
        }
    }

    //To calculate the divide by 4 ( result/4 ) in this case
    if(symbol == '+')
        result += Integer.parseInt(num)
    else if(symbol == '-')
        result -= Integer.parseInt(num)
    else if(symbol == '*')
        result *= Integer.parseInt(num)
    else if(symbol == '/')
        result /= Integer.parseInt(num)

    println("result is $result") //Output=> result is 6
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No you can't.

You can like this:

```
val a = "2"
val b = "2"
val c = a.toInt() + b.toInt()
```

Or

```
val input = "2+2"
val s = input.split("+")
val result = s[0].toInt() + s[1].toInt()
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with the kotlin script engine. For details see [Dynamically evaluating templated Strings in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44009515/dynamically-evaluating-templated-strings-in-kotlin)

But in a nutshell it's like this:

```
val engine = ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByExtension("kts")!!
engine.eval("val x = 3")
val res = engine.eval("x + 2")
Assert.assertEquals(5, res)
```

Answer (score -2):

No, Integer cannot be equal to math expression.

You may use String Templates

Strings may contain template expressions, i.e. pieces of code that are evaluated and whose results are concatenated into the
string.

A template expression starts with a dollar sign ($) and consists of either a simple name:

```
  val i = 10
  val s = "i = $i" // evaluates to "i = 10"
```

Comment: Those cannot convert `"2+2"` to an `Int`.

Comment: updated my answer. please check if up vote is possible.