# Run Kotlin stored as a string is giving a runtime error

Tags: android, kotlin

Based on [Dynamically evaluating templated Strings in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44009515/dynamically-evaluating-templated-strings-in-kotlin), I've tried, for special and rares uses, run *Kotlin* scripts stored as strings. My `Android Studio` is updated (3.4.1). My computer runs `Windows`.

The script test is stored [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/examples/kotlin-jsr223-local-example/src/test/kotlin/org/jetbrains/kotlin/script/jsr223/KotlinJsr223ScriptEngineIT.kt).

I've added `JS223.Jar` file in the `libs` folder, added as a library and put a dependence in the gradle (app).

The source code is

```
import javax.script.*


val engine = ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByExtension("kts")!!
engine.eval("val x = 3")
val res = engine.eval("x + 2")
```

Based on a real usage, I've copied from *JetBrain/Kotlin* in [GitHub](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/compiler/cli/cli-common/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/cli/common/environment/util.kt) the `setIdeaIoUseFallback()` code without dependence

However, with or without `setIdeaIoUseFallback()` previous call , the above code gives a crazy runtime error in `ScriptEngineManager()` call

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lsun/misc/Service
Javax.script.ScriptEngineManager.initEngines(ScriptEngineManager.java:90)
javax.script.ScriptEngineManager.access$0(ScriptEngineManager.java:86)
javax.script.ScriptEngineManager$1.run(ScriptEngineManager.java:80)
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:41)
javax.script.ScriptEngineManager.init(ScriptEngineManager.java:78)
javax.script.ScriptEngineManager.<init>(ScriptEngineManager.java:51)    
br.com.greatsolutions.paulo.kotlinfirst.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:65)
```

Answer (score 1):

I made my code run by adding the following dependencies in my gradle script

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"

    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-compiler-embeddable"
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-script-util"
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-script-runtime"

    runtime "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-scripting-compiler-embeddable"
}
```

Also I added the  file in resources\META_INF\services\javax.script.ScriptEngineFactory with the following content:

```
org.jetbrains.kotlin.script.jsr223.KotlinJsr223JvmLocalScriptEngineFactory
```

I was then able to run the following code

```
setIdeaIoUseFallback()
val engine = ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByExtension("kts")!!
engine.eval("val x = 3")
val res = engine.eval("x + 2")
Assertions.assertEquals(5, res)
```